# How to reference an expanded Highslide object through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, highslide

I am trying to create a small function that will allow a user to click anywhere on a webpage to close an expanded image created through highslide. A bug that popped up was when the image can't fully expand, you have the option to expand it to full size or leave it in the bounds of your browser, however, I have the highslide element triggered to close on any click event. I came up with this work around that still has some issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/hs/highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/hs/highslide/highslide.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                                                                
var mState=false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
$(document).click(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  hs.Expander.prototype.onMouseOver = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    mState = false;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    console.log('over') };                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  hs.Expander.prototype.onMouseOut = function() {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    mState = true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    console.log('out')  };                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  console.log(mState);                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  if (mState) hs.close();                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}); </script>

<a href="/pub/opdc/p0000/tall.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="/pub/opdc/p0000/tall_t.jpg" alt="Highslide JS" align="right"></a>
```

I am only just learning java script/jQuery and highslide so I apologize for bad practice. Console.log is strictly for debugging and will be removed.

My question is specifically as follows. I want to reference the expanded highslide image through jQuery so I don't have to use highslide's mouse events. I am finding them to be to unpredictable and I don't have the time right now to suss out exactly how they work and why I am not seeing the results I want.

Hopefully that all made sense, thank you in advance for any and all assistance.

Comment: This is hard to reproduce... Can you create a Fiddle or CodePen ? And post what is `hs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in having fun with this little mind puzzle of a problem, this is the final and active code I am running on my websites now for added "click to close" functionality without using the dimmer method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mState=false;
  hs.Expander.prototype.onMouseOver = function() { mState = false; }
  hs.Expander.prototype.onMouseOut  = function() { mState = true;  }
  jQuery(document).click(function() {
    if (mState) {
      hs.close();
      mState = false;
    }
  } );
</script>
```

For this code to work you need to use highslide-full.js. I hope this helps someone out or provides you with some fun like it did with me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand why you're trying to reinvent the wheel. Highslide JS already has this functionality built in. If you set the dimming opacity to any non-zero value, clicking anywhere on the page will close the expander.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   hs.dimmingOpacity = 0.75;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.highslide-dimming {
    background: black;
}
</style>
```

If you don't actually want a dimmed background, just set the value to something like 0.0001.

Comment: That feels like to much of a cheater method to me, I like for my code to have one purpose and execute that purpose efficiently. The primary function of the dimmer is to dim the background of the screen, as a byproduct of the method, it also happens to close the screen. I ended up figuring out the issue, I needed to default my mouse flag back to false after closing the image and it now works beautifully.

Comment: Do you want the page to behave a certain way, or are you more concerned with some mythical code purity? Using jQuery is the "cheater method." You're introducing an unnecessary script to accomplish something that Highslide JS can already do on its own. Love overhead, much?

Comment: I'd say I fall into the realm of mythical code purity more than anything. Beyond that it is also my boss who likes code written to do it's job and by his mindset, using the dimmer isn't doing the job correctly. I would agree it makes sense to use the dimmer as it is easy and clean and does exactly what I need. But rules are tight here so it's easier for me to take the longer path from the get-go.

Plus on top of that, I am trying to force myself to solve weird problems like this so I can learn the API's of all these tools that I am very new to.

Comment: You'd be surprised at the history of the addition of "dimming" to the script. Without it, it was possible to open multiple expanders, then reposition them. So, you couldn't have an expander close if you clicked outside of it - you might simply have been opening or repositioning another one. With a dimmed background, of course, that changed. In fact, the "close on click outside" was an INTENTIONAL change, not just an accident. Using a dimmer is, in fact, the correct way to do the job. It's what the script developer intended. I was there. (Continued in next comment...)

Comment: Taking the long path is never smart coding - using the script as intended is the smart move. BTW, you could also treat dimmingOpacity as a boolean, as either 0 or 1. Set it to 1, then set the background color to transparent. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it without having to drag jQuery into the mix, using only the tools that Highslide JS provides, and without having to be "offended" by using a sneaky shortcut:

```
hs.addEventListener(document, 'click', function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

   // if the target element is not within an expander but there is an expander on the page, close it
   if (!hs.getExpander(target) && hs.getExpander()) hs.close();
});
```

(Originally posted six years ago by Torstein, the Highslide JS developer.)